# Please recommend a graphics library for drawing vector graphics and event handling (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, vector-graphics

I need a graphics library with the ability to handle events like mouse hover/click/keystrokes and draw vector graphics. I don't need libraries like tkinter or something similar, I need something simpler to just draw SVG-style shapes and handle events. I wanna make my interface manually.

P.S. Not pygame, it's too slow for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best user-friendly graphics library is Turtle.  Turtle is a built-in Python library that manually allows you to draw  graphics using vectors/X-Y coordinates to draw using the 'turtle' which is a fancy way of saying 'pen' in Python.  No need to use pip, this library is built in.  All you need to do is call it in using: from turtle import *
Turtle is simple, but can lead to G.U.I development even though it is not technically a G.U.I but a tool for widget development as well.  Again, Turtle is overlooked by many Python programmers (including myself unfortunately), but it is very powerful for being user-friendly and basic.  Below is a link to the Turtle library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

I hope this helps!!!:)